# Update Angular 7 to Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

This is my package.json

```
"@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
"@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
"@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
```

I did all the steps to update my project from angular 7 to 8,
but it generates the following error  when executing ng serve:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts:13:10 - error 
TS2305: Module '"../../../cdk/stepper"' has no exported member 'CdkStepHeader'.

13 import { CdkStepHeader, StepState } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts:13:25 - error TS2305: 
Module '"../../../cdk/stepper"' has no exported member 'StepState'.

13 import { CdkStepHeader, StepState } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
                       ~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-icon.d.ts:9:10 - error TS2305: 
Module '"../../../cdk/stepper"' has no exported member 'StepState'.
```

This is my angular configuration.

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.21
Node: 10.16.3
Angular: 8.2.14

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.21
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.21
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/cli                      8.3.21
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.21
@schematics/angular               8.3.21
@schematics/update                0.803.21
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

I already searched the web and found these answers but they don't work for me

[information](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/issues/231)

This is the command that should solve the problem, as I understand @ angular / material @ angular / cdk and angular should be in the latest version

```
    npm install --save @ angular / material @ angular / cdk
```

I appreciate your collaboration to solve this, thank you very much :)

Comment: You need to update `@angular/cdk` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cdk

Comment: ng update, then remove your package-lock.json and node_modules and run npm install again

Comment: :) work to me! Thanks men!

Answer (score 3):

Please update your `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/common` to the version `^8.2.14`.

You just need to change those versions in the `package.json` dependency.

To make sure that everything works like expected I recommend the following order:

1. Go into your `package.json`
2. Replace every `@angular` dependency version to a consistent version number. Here you can find what feature you can expect from which version: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
3. Remove your `node_modules/` folder
4. Reinstall your dependencies with `npm install` for npm or `yarn install` for yarn